# How can I change the colour of individual squares on this grid...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a game where a user has to move a character around a grid and collect passengers. I have managed to construct this grid using some CSS and jQuery however I need to change the colour of individual squares within the grid as I need to include three types of terrain.

At the moment I have kept it all in one file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>BotMod</title>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }

  ul{list-style:none;}
  a{text-decoration:none;}


  #grid{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:#eee;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
  }

  .box{
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin:4px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
  }

</style>

<style id="jsbin-css">

</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="grid"></div>



<script>
var boxX = 0;
var boxY = 0;
var box = '<div class="box" />';

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
  $('#grid').append(box);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I am asking is how can I change the colour of each square to a colour of my choice? If any one could show any code examples that would be very helpful as I am still learning JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: add class or nth child or inline styles....have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "eq()"-selector will help you here:

If you want to get the second box in your grid you can simply add ":eq(2)" to your selector:

```
$('#grid .box:eq(2)').css('background', '#f00');
```

Comment: Thank you that works great, I didn't realise that would be so simple :)